# Round values before SUM()

Tags: excel

Our customers use formulas in their input fields. Thats why their values sometimes contain decimal places. We can't round each field, cause it would be overrided by their formulas and input.

I have a field, which requires numbers with no decimal places.
Is there a possibility to SUM() the ROUNDED values, something like a ROUND() function that uses a range of inputs?

Comment: you want to round a number right?

Answer (score 8):

I think what you may want is something like this:

```
=SUM(ROUND(A1:C1,0))
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. The `0` is for the extent of rounding (no decimal places) but can be increased. So with data in each of A1:C1 (the range may be increased) of `12.4` the result is `36`, with data of `12.6` the result is `39`.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to your problem is a combination of using both the SUM and the ROUND functions together. The effect is that you will get sum of rounded numbers.  Here is how it looks:

Suppose we want to add the numbers from B2 to B6, you should do:
`{=SUM(ROUND(B2:B6,0))}`

Let's look at the parts:

ROUND(B2:B6,0)-  We will round each of the numbers to a whole number when we do the sum. 0 indicates no decimal points.

=SUM(ROUND(B2:B6,0))-  We put a Sum around it to add the rounded numbers

{=SUM(ROUND(B2:B6,0))}-  The finishing touch- important- we save the formula by clicking the Ctrl, Shift and Enter keys at the same time, since this is an array.  This puts the brackets around the formula.  If we just finished the formula by clicking Enter, we would get an error.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried above I got an error. Resolved by putting the round first.
=ROUND(SUM(B2:B6),0)

I used this with the following to convert then whole number (currency) to words.
=SpellNumber(B7) 
where B7 is the cell with the previous formula.

Comment: Although this removes the error, it will give incorrect results. Summing before the round can give different answers than rounding before the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the sum function before round would cause the process to be slow and at times result in error. The best method would be

```
=round(sum(b2:b6),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing the round function before sum would result in an incorrect entry.

Example:
Assume two cells B2 & B3 are value 1.5

Using

`=sum(round(b2:b3,0))`

...the returned result would be 4. Both cells are rounded to 2 and then added. But using

`=round(sum(b2:b3),0)`

...the result would be 3. Both cells are added and the result rounded.